# @import some attribute not work in @layer tailwindcss

Tags: layer, tailwind-css

Destructing the file and all import to the tailwindcss.css file. It failed when i import from other file instead write it in tailwind.css.

Use layer to apply custom font family and text-3xl (working in this way)

```css
// tailwind.css
@tailwind base;
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply font-heading text-3xl;
  }
}
```

@import from outside css file, it cannot work as usual. The font-heading is work, but **font-size**(text-3xl) **is not working**.

```css
@tailwind base;
@layer base {
  @import "./fonts/index.css";
}
```

```
// fonts/index.css
h1 {
  @apply font-heading text-3xl
}
```

What i guess:

1. it load @import css first before load **@tailwind base**, default base will overwrite my **h1** font-size to tailwindcss default.

Do any workaorund could avoid this behavior in tailwindcss? it look messy if all style in tailwindcss file.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74943254/11710789

Also posted there ^^^

I found something that seems to work for me.
Basically postcss-import has its own layer system that we can use instead of tailwinds layer system.

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base' layer(Base);
@import './base/typography.css' layer(Base);

@import 'tailwindcss/components' layer(Components);

@import 'tailwindcss/utilities' layer(Utilities);

@layer Base {
  #root {
    @apply some-styles;
  }
}
```

In [postcss-import#usage](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import#usage) it describes using `layer()` with `@import`

```css
...
@import 'baz.css' layer(baz-layer);
...
```

I used uppercase layer names to avoid conflicting with tailwinds layers.

Install postcss-import as described in tailwinds article.
[using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports)
Then add `layer()` to your imports like `@import 'tailwindcss/base' layer(Base).`
Also rename your `@layers` calls to something different than tailwinds layers.

For examples you can look any of the test fixtures with `layer` in the filename.
[postcss-import/test/fixtures](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/tree/master/test/fixtures)

## UPDATE

The root cause of this is using Create React App.
Because it doesn't allow you to configure `postcss.config.js`.

So another solution would be to migrate to something else instead.

- [darekkay/create-react-app-to-vite#migration](https://darekkay.com/blog/create-react-app-to-vite/#migration)
- [tailwindcss.com/issues/1472](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/issues/1472)
- [tailwindcss/guides/create-react-app](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

> we highly recommend using Vite, Next.js, Remix, or Parcel instead of Create React App