# Using NextJS, how can you import in CSS using tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

Just started using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) in a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project.

I set it up through my CSS file, and was trying to setup some basics for headers `h1`, `h2`, ... but I like separating the logic a bit so it doesn't get too messy, so I tried to `@import './typography.css' which includes some tailwind, but it doesn't work.

Here is my base CSS file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;

@import './typography.css';
```

My typography:

```css
h1 {
    @apply text-6xl font-normal leading-normal mt-0 mb-2;
}
...
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

**Update**

I've tried:

- Added `@layer base` in my typography.css file, but receive an error: `Syntax error: /typography.css "@layer base" is used but no matching @tailwind base`
- Also tried do it at the import layer, eg `@layer base { @import("typography.css") }`, that doesn't create an error but the styles aren't applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [docs from tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports), here is a TLDR;

Install

```
npm install -D postcss-import
```

Update your `postcss.config.js`

```js
// /postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        "postcss-import": {}, // <= Add this
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

Then in your main css file where you have the imports, you need to:

- rename the `tailwindcss` imports to from `@import base;` to `@import "tailwindcss/base";` (same for the `components` and `utilities`
- Then you need to import in the proper order. If the file is a `base` put it after the `base` import, it's a `components`, put it after the `components`

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base"; // <= used to be `@tailwind base;`
@import "./custom-base-styles.css";

@import "tailwindcss/components"; // <= used to be `@tailwind components;`
@import "./custom-components.css";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities"; // <= used to be `@tailwind utilities;`
@import "./custom-utilities.css";
```

Then in your `custom-base-styles.css` you can:

```css
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-3xl text-slate-800;
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work in my setup when I attempted it. `custom-base-styles.css '@layer base' is used but no matching '@tailwind base' directive is present.`

I believe the purpose of @layer is to more the css to the location the @tailwind directive is called.

So if you import your custom styles under the tailwind @imports then you shouldn't need to use @layers.

Also note that using the @tailwind directives within a custom file duplicates the definitions for all the css.

Comment: I've updated the title to make it more clear, this should work for Next JS projects, not sure about Create React App.

Answer (score 3):

You need set the target layer for this to work.
Since you want to change the base html elements in your `typography.css` file do:

```css
@layer base {
    h1 {
        @apply text-6xl font-normal leading-normal mt-0 mb-2;
    }
}
```

More details in the documentation here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles

Comment: So, I put `@layer base {... }` inside my typography.css file and I'm now getting this error: `Syntax error: /typography.css "@layer base" is used but no matching `@tailwind base` directive is present.`

Comment: PS I also tried doing `@layer base { @import("typography.css") }`, which doesn't create an error but it doesn't apply the style.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports) the issue is a matter of the order of the statements. They recommend to put the `@tailwind base;` statement in a seperate file and import it like this:

```css
@import "./tailwind-base-statement.css";
@import "./typography.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `postcss-import`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-multiple-css-files

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports

if you use Laravel webpack mix, add it in `.postCss(....)`

```js
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'), // <------------ add postcss-import here
    require('tailwindcss'),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. used poscss and [postcss-import-plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports) import plugin

   npm install -D postcss-import

2. update `postcss.config.js` file

   module.exports = {
   plugins: {
   'postcss-import': {},
   tailwindcss: {},
   }
   }
3. add `@tailwind base;` inside top of your `typography.css`

for more deatils you can check this link:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to work for me.
Basically postcss-import has its own layer system that we can use instead of tailwinds layer system.

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base' layer(Base);
@import './base/typography.css' layer(Base);

@import 'tailwindcss/components' layer(Components);

@import 'tailwindcss/utilities' layer(Utilities);

@layer Base {
  #root {
    @apply some-styles;
  }
}
```

In [postcss-import#usage](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import#usage) it describes using `layer()` with `@import`

```css
...
@import 'baz.css' layer(baz-layer);
...
```

I used uppercase layer names to avoid conflicting with tailwinds layers.

Install postcss-import as described in tailwinds article.
[using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports)
Then add `layer()` to your imports like `@import 'tailwindcss/base' layer(Base).`
Also rename your `@layers` calls to something different than tailwinds layers.

For examples you can look any of the test fixtures with `layer` in the filename.
[postcss-import/test/fixtures](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/tree/master/test/fixtures)

## UPDATE

The root cause of this for me was using Create React App.
Because it doesn't allow you to configure `postcss.config.js`.

So another solution would be to migrate to something else instead.

- [darekkay/create-react-app-to-vite#migration](https://darekkay.com/blog/create-react-app-to-vite/#migration)
- [tailwindcss.com/issues/1472](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/issues/1472)
- [tailwindcss/guides/create-react-app](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

> we highly recommend using Vite, Next.js, Remix, or Parcel instead of Create React App

Answer (score 0):

In NextJs projects, we may get some errors after the import process. Especially if we use @layer components in the file we import in the NextJs project, we may get errors. I will explain a detailed solution to prevent these errors.

Firstly, let's move the file we imported to the top.

```
@import './typography.css';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then install these two packages.

```
npm i postcss-import
npm i postcss-nesting
```

Then edit our postcss.config.js file as follows.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': 'postcss-nesting',
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Finally, stop and restart the terminal.